# How to Calculate the Lebesgue Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

## Question

$\psi(x, y) = \psi_x(y) = e^{xy}, \cosh{x} = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$.

Why is the following valid? What is the detailed calculation?
$$
\cosh{x} = \int_\mathbb{R}\psi_x d\mu,\ \mu := \frac{1}{2}\delta_1 + \frac{1}{2}\delta_{-1}
$$
Note that $\delta_\alpha$ is the delta measure with respect to the point $\alpha$.

## What I know

$$
\int_\mathbb{R}\psi_x d\mu = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{xy} d\mu = \cdots\ ??
$$
I can't think of any further deformations because the function under integration is not a measurable simple function.

Comment: You asked a very similar question recently at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627432/how-to-handle-measurements-and-lebesgue-integrals-with-concrete-example where your primary issue is that you don't appear to have a working definition of the integral of non-simple functions. Please see if the answer there does anything to solve your problem. I do suspect that the best answer that can be offered here is to read further until you actually have a definition of the integral for non-simple functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any measurable function $f$ we have $\int fd\mu=\frac 1 2[f(1)+f(-1)]$. So $\int\psi_xd\mu=\frac 1 2[\psi_x(1)+\psi_x(-1)]=\frac {e^{x}+e^{-x}}2$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this hold for any measurable $f$? Is this a theorem?

Comment: @CBBAM Verify it for simple functions first and then go through the usual porcess of proving it for non-negative meaurable functions and then for all meaurable functions

Comment: Let $f = 10\mathbb{I}_{\{-1\}} + \mathbb{I}_{(-1, 1]}$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. Then $\int f d\mu = 10 \cdot \mu(\{-1\}) + \mu((-1, 1]) = 0 + 2 \neq \frac{1}{2}[f(1) + f(-1)] = \frac{11}{2}$. Is this not a counterexample or have I made a mistake?

Comment: $\mu$ is given in the question. Obviously what I have written is not true for all measures. It is only true for the given measure. @CBBAM

Comment: Sorry, that careless from me.