# Integral with measure defined via integral

Tags: measure-theory

we define

$ \mu(A):= \int_{A}^{} \frac{1}{x}dx$ for all $ A \in B([1,\infty)$ where $ B([1,\infty))$ is the Borel-Algebra regarding $ [1,\infty)$.

Now consider the measure space ([1, ∞), B([1, ∞)), µ).

My question is why doesn't $\int_{[1,\infty)}^{} x 
*1_{[1,2]} d\mu=2$ hold? The solutions from the exam I'm looking at don't explain why it isn't true but I'm not really sure how to even evaluate this integral feasibly. Would I need to actually construct a sequence that converges towards the function or is there an easier way? If I'd need to construct such a sequence I suppose I could work it out on my own, it just seems like it's a lot of work for an exercise that's supposed to give  almost no points so I'm suspecting I'm missing a tool or something here that would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Presumably, the result should be $(2 - 1) = 1$ rather than $2$

Comment: This is similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627432/how-to-handle-measurements-and-lebesgue-integrals-with-concrete-example/4628172#4628172

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{[1, \infty)} x\chi_{[1, 2]} \,d\mu = \int_{[1, \infty)} x \chi_{[1, 2]} \frac{1}{x} \,dx = \int_{[1, \infty)} \chi_{[1, 2]} \,dx = |[1, 2]| = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, that way it's as trivial as the exercise points make it seem. What is the rule or the name of it you use in the first step?

Comment: @VeryGenericUsername This is a standard result for measures induced by nonnegative measurable function integrals: $\int_X f \,d\mu = \int_X f g \,d\lambda$, where $\mu(A) = \int_A g \,d\lambda$, where $g$ is a nonnegative measurable function. To prove, start with $f$ being a simple function, then move onto nonnegative functions through MCT, then general integrable functions with positive and negative parts.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Thank you very much!